# Continuity of the partial derivatives of $F_\alpha(x)=x||x||^\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

Given $\alpha>0$ define $F_\alpha:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ as $$F_\alpha(x)=x||x||^\alpha$$

I must prove that $F_\alpha\in\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^n)$.

With some calculation I found that $$\frac{\partial(F_\alpha)_j}{\partial x_i}=\alpha x_jx_i||x||^{\alpha-2}=\alpha x_jx_i\frac{||x||^\alpha}{||x||^2}$$

Based on this result I would conclude that either $\alpha$ must be greater than $2$ (and not greater than $0$ as the exercise says) or $F_\alpha\in\mathcal C(\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\})$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us drop the subscript $\alpha$.
It holds
$$
\partial_i F_j (x) =
\begin{cases}
 \delta_{ij} |x|^{\alpha} + \alpha x_i x_j |x|^{\alpha -2},
& \text{if}\ x\neq 0,\\
0, 
&\text{if}\ x = 0.
\end{cases} 
$$
(The partial derivatives at $x=0$ must be computed using the definition.)

It is easily seen that these partial derivatives are continuous. Namely, they are clearly continuous at points $x\neq 0$, whereas at $x=0$ it is sufficient to prove that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \partial_i F_j (x) = 0.
$$
But this condition is easily verified (for $\alpha > 0$) since
$$
|\partial_i F_j(x)| \leq |x|^\alpha + \alpha |x|^2 |x|^{\alpha -2}
= (1+\alpha) |x|^\alpha.
$$